# BindingExpressing in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

How to use BindingExpression for Listbox?

For textbox we use something like

BindingExpression bindingExpression = txtbox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

Thanks 
Sharath

Comment: I was doing some thing ugly.. it is working now. 
BindingExpression bindingExpression = Listbox1.GetBindingExpression(ListBox.SelectedValueProperty);

Answer (score 1):

The same way? `GetBindingExpression` is defined for `FrameworkElement`, and `ListBox` is one.